# Storage location of information on what page the user is reading in Reader

Tags: adobe-reader, foxit-reader

Adobe Acrobat Reader and Foxit Reader both have a feature that allows them to remember what was the last page the user was reading.

Where do these PDF readers (both Adobe and Foxit) store such information?

Comment: Your earlier post version would seek to have an innumerable list of Readers.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the registry. For instance, Foxit Reader stores that information at the following location:
`HKCU\Software\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader 5.0\Preferences\History\LastOpen`
(The exact path might be slightly different for different versions.)

Ther's a subkey for each recently opened file, and a value called `Page` stores the page number where that file was opened last.

Comment: Any idea on where Adobe Acrobat should keep this?

Comment: I don't have Adobe Reader installed on any of my computers so can't check, but try searching through `HKCU\Software\Adobe` and its subkeys.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, I think this kind of data can be stored as [metadata for the PDF](http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/metadata), which is basically just key-value pairs.

In other cases it might be stored by the particular application used to open/modify the PDF (the location would then vary from application to application).